# How to integrate payment gateway in Hybris?

Tags: stripe-payments, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a requirement where i need to integrate **Stripe** payment gateway to my Hybris storefront. While doing R&D in help.hybris.com i have come across two things, **CIS framework** and **payment extension**. CIS framework provides one of the service called cispayment. So what my question is, what is the difference between cispayment and payment extension. Which has the more advantages? and what should i go with.

P.S. I have searched for stripe in Hybris marketplace, unfortunately i found nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

You need a lot of customization for integrating payment mode. You can check OOTB payment providers. Also you can check adyen integration at https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-hybris

Comment: Thank you mate. i found that link very useful. i have also gone through [cybersource](http://www.hybris.com/en/products/extensions/cybersource) , but i'm not sure whether they have implemented with **Payment extension**, if you find some time can you go through that link and tell me whether they used **Payment Extension**

Answer (score 0):

You can do both with and without CIS extension along with Payment extension. Only at the time of authorisation, you will be using CIS API instead of payment extension's API directly if you choose to use CIS API. I hope you are choosing to prefer to do Generation and Settlement in ERP instead of Hybris in case it is still not implemented. That way you will save cronjob and delay in settlement and also keep ERP payment scalable.

Payment extension if available should always be used, this will lead you to not change your code when you are upgrading hybris version. The payment extension will also be upgraded by vendor at that time. If you don't use extension, you will have to unjar the library and do your changes which is as tough as it sounds.